# Configure IIS to connect to SQL Server using Active Directory account

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have created a group on AD, and configured this group to have access to my SQL Server. With it, any .Net app, SQL Server and SSIS are able to connect to SQL Server using any AD account that's on that group, they just need to set Trusted Connection/Windows Authentication.

Now I need to do the same on IIS apps. But I have never configured IIS and don't know how to do it. I Googled it, but everything refers to user authenticating to IIS using NTLM, not IIS connecting to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Server2008 and higher you will likely want to use Application Pool Identity.  This article helped get me going when I set up an IIS / SQL Application.

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

EDIT:
Specifically where it demonstrates how to use a built in account there is an option to choose a custom account.
https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Running-Secret-Server-IIS-Application-Pool-with-a-Service-Account

EDIT2:
Using windows auth - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/

Comment: Thanks. That article explains a lot. But I can't find where will I define the AD account that will connect to MSSQL.

Comment: We run IIS with Basic Auth in our domain. In Auth rules we determine who (users, groups etc) can access to our site. All connection to DB run under the user that connects.

Comment: @gofr1 do you mean the user that's on the browser is the one that's used to log on the DB? How do you config it? do you give users direct access to DB?

Comment: You can use windows auth, passed through to the sql server.  Depending on if your SQL and IIS are on the same hardware, you may have to configure kerberos to handle the double-hop.  I will edit answer with an article.

Comment: @Hikari yes, same auth to our domain. I have installed AD components on my computer (running Win 7 when it was in development of cause, now it is running on Windows Server 20.. don't remember) throw Control Panel -> Add and remove programs -> Turn on or off Windows features and enable basic auth in IIS config manager. Yes, direct access, previously we use Access 2003 to work with DB, after changing to online service - group policy remained unchanged.