# MS SQL Native Client Login failed for user when connecting via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sqlsrv

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter server with IIS 7.5, MS SQL 2012 Express, using PHP 5.6 trying to connect to a database I created, testDB, via Windows Authentication, but am failing to do so.

Here is my PHP I am using to connect to my SQL Server\Instance:

```
<?php

$serverName = "nmc-intranet\intranetsql";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"testDB", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ( $conn ) {
echo "Connection successful.<br />";
} else {
    echo "Connection failed.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

When I run this I receive:

> Connection failed.
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/) => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'jaj'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'jaj'. ) [1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/) => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/) => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'jaj'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'jaj'. ) )

In MS SQL I have added the username to the Security > Logins and mapped testDB and gave dbo schema.  User also has sysadmin Server Role.  I can connect to testDB via CLI `SQLCMD /S nmc-intranet\intranetSQL /E /d testDB` under the username.  I can also connect to the Server\Instance via a remote SSMS session so I believe the remote connection properties are correct.  I have verified the steps mentioned in the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276873/issues-connecting-to-microsoft-sql-from-php?rq=1).

For IIS I have tried establishing the connection many different ways, but also unsuccessful there.  So I have been assuming that is where my issue lies in the SQL login failed error.  I have been changing the connection string via the IIS Manager under the NMC-Intranet Node and also the Default Web Site Node and failed there.  My current connection string in web.config is what was in there by default after making changes in IIS Manger, and is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add connectionString="Server=nmc-intranet;Database=testDB;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tried changing it to the following that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474941/connection-string-between-iis-and-sql-server), and still have had no success.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testDB;User ID=username;Password=password" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In IIS DefaultAppPool I have tried changing the Process Model Identity to the username/password there as well.  I have been reading about Kerberos authentication [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/), but when the intranet is accessed with it enabled it prompts users for a username/password to even view the home page.

I hope I asked this question correctly as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as previous questions were not well-received.  I have done a lot of researching, but I do not know what I could be missing, and I have made so many changes and reverted them as they did not work I am just hoping for some direction of what I might need to try next.  I have most likely misinterpreted something, as I do not have a complete understanding of how the connection needs to be established, and skipped a step or overlooked some information.

I am no professional here just trying to gather this all together from the internet, make it work, and hopefully learn something.

End game I am looking to have users log in to Intranet via AD, and upload files, create their own posts, create a directory of sorts that can be managed via the intranet, possibly have an IM(?), and really just the learning experience.

Thank you.

Comment: You should check SQL Server error log for this "login failed". The next row will explain you the reason of failure

Comment: @sepupic Thank you for the suggestion I will defiantly check the log first next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

If you want to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication, remove `UID` and `PWD` connection options. When you use these options, then PHP Driver tries to connect using SQL Server authentication (I guees that `jaj` is the value for `UID`).

```
<?php
$serverName = "nmc-intranet\intranetsql";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database"=>"testDB"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Connection failed.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo "Connection successful.<br />";
}
?>
```

**Explanations:**

The Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server can connect to SQL Server by using [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-2017) or by using [SQL Server Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-sql-server-authentication?view=sql-server-2017).
When you use Windows Authentication, then the Web server's process identity or thread identity
(if the Web server is using impersonation) is used to connect to the server, not an end-user's identity. I use this script to get more information:

```
<?php
# ---------------------------------------
# SQL Server authentication
# ---------------------------------------
echo "SQL Server authentication"."</br>";
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'master',
    "UID"=>'login',
    "PWD"=>'password'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$sql = 
    "SELECT 'SUSER_SNAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SUSER_SNAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'SUSER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SUSER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), USER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_ID' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), USER_ID()) AS [VALUE]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['NAME'].": ".$row['VALUE']."</br>";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);


# ---------------------------------------
# Windows authentication
# ---------------------------------------
echo "Windows authentication"."</br>";
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'master'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$sql = 
    "SELECT 'SUSER_SNAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SUSER_SNAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'SUSER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SUSER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), USER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_ID' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), USER_ID()) AS [VALUE]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['NAME'].": ".$row['VALUE']."</br>";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this I am now receiving a connection successful.  I added the bottom part of the code you provided and it is connecting with `USER_NAME: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.  I do not know if I just completely missed UID/PWD was for SQL Authentication or misunderstood.  I did assume that if I am allowing jaj to the SQL server the connection needed to use the same.  Now I am wondering how to restrict users access to the SQL database using Windows Authentication?  I have read it is more secure or maybe I misunderstood.  Either way hopefully I will read more carefully in the future.

Comment: @Leavii You must set appropriate IIS authentication mode. If you see `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` as user name, I guess it is anonymous.

Comment: It is defiantly something I am going to have to research more on.  I had read on how to connect IIS to MS SQL, but I am having trouble finding that source.  The tutorial did state to set my DefaultAppPool's Process Model Identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService.  Then allow NetworkService access to MS SQL.  So far I have found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575752/configure-iis-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-active-directory-account,  and hopefully this will get me going in the correct direction.

Comment: Removed NetworkService, and now receive `Cannot open database "testDB" requested by the login. The login failed` so I got some more work to do.  That link above is where I had read about the Kerberos, but I need to re-read as I did not see where there is an option to not require users to sign in to the intranet even at the homepage.