# Not able to connect to SQL Server DB using PHP 7

Tags: php, sql-server

Am working on a PHP web development and using the following infrastructure characteristics:

- **OS:** Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- **DB:** Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit)
- **PHP:** v7.3

I was trying to use the following code which I found in many forums but failed to get connect to the database I created:

```
    <?php

$myServer = "MyMachine\SQLEXPRESS";
$myUser = "";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "firstDb";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$myDB, "UID" => $myUser, "PWD" => $myPass);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo); //returns false

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Successfuly connected.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection error.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Unfortunately am unable to get connected to the database and only getting the below message:

```
Connection error. 
   Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
         [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 
         [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 
         [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. 
         [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. )

      [1] => Array ( 
         [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 
         [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 
         [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "firstDb" requested by the login. The login failed. 
         [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "firstDb" requested by the login. The login failed. ) 

      [2] => Array ( 
         [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 
         [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 
         [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. 
         [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) 

      [3] => Array ( 
         [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 
         [1] => 4060 
         [code] => 4060 
         [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "firstDb" requested by the login. The login failed. 
         [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "firstDb" requested by the login. The login failed. )
   )
```

Can you please help me fixing this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest attempting the exact same connection but without using code, e.g. sign onto the server and use SQL Management Studio to connect to the database. If that doesn't work either, the problem is not your PHP code.

Comment: At the SQL Server Management Studio level am using the Windows Authentication am not using any specific credentials.

Comment: @developer202122 This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525593/ms-sql-native-client-login-failed-for-user-when-connecting-via-php/53534045#53534045) may help. With empty user and password you are trying to conect to SQL Server using windows authentication and the web server's process identity. With SQL Server Management Studio you are using agaian windows authentication, but the credentials are different. As a test, use may try to SQL Server authentiaction to connect to the server.