# Cannot connect to SQL 2019 with service account from IIS web server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo, windows-server

I have a PHP application running on a Windows Server 2019 IIS (I think it is IIS 8.5). We are soon going to change our database setup from a SQL 2012 with local SQL accounts to a SQL 2019 with Windows service accounts and I do have a problem connecting to that setup.

My problem is that I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'mydomain\myuser'.

I have updated everything to the newest stable versions:

- PHP is `7.4.11`
- PHP `pdo_sqlsrv` version is `5.8.0+12928`
- PHP `sqlsrv` version is `5.8.0+12928`
- Windows ODBC version `17.6`

I have double-checked with [System Requirements for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-version-certified-compatibility) that everything seems correct and that I am using supported versions - and I am.

I am connecting with this PHP (PDO) code:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:Server='fqdn.myserver';Database='MyDatabase'",
        "mydomain\\myuser",
        "mysecretpassword"
    );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

I have also tried another approach with regular SQL and not PDO:

```
$conn = array(
    "UID" => "mydomain\\myuser",
    "PWD" => "mysecretpassword",
    "Database" => "MyDatabase",
    "Encrypt" => true,
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true,
    "LoginTimeout" => 30,
);

$sql = sqlsrv_connect("fqdn.myserver", $conn);
if(!$sql) {
    exit(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
```

.. but with same error. The exact same code works fine with the SQL 2012 database (different user).

The interesting thing is that I can (from my web server) connect to the SQL 2019 database with SQL Management Studio with that same `myuser` account if I do a `RunAs` command:

```
runas.exe /USER:mydomain\myuser /netonly "path_to_MSSQLSrvMgmtStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

Also I can connect to the SQL 2019 database if I am connecting with a SQL account - then everything works fine but sadly this is not an option for me :-/

I am not aware if I need to do anything special in my PHP code if this is a **Windows service account** I connect with? Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525593/ms-sql-native-client-login-failed-for-user-when-connecting-via-php/53534045#53534045).

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages that may include more details about the reason for the login failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Active Directory service accounts, then the authentication to the database should be handled through IIS. This means that the IIS "Application Pool" should be setup with the new service account user and then the PHP database connection should **not** include any credentials.

So it should actually be identical to the above PDO connection string, except that it should exclude the username/password part. It should look like this::

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:Server='fqdn.myserver';Database='MyDatabase'"
    );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

In IIS you should create a new *Application Pool* entry and associate the service account with it. Then on the folder in IIS, that you want to authenticate with this service account, then you click *Convert to Application* and you should select the newly created application pool for it. Make sure that the service account have access to the files in the web folder.

You can also use the service account on the default assigned application pool.

This is working for me at least :-)